# Getting value of field with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

This is my page:

http://bryntum.com/examples/gantt-latest/examples/basic/basic.html

I want to get **current** value of Start and Finish date.
( I will later implement a button, that user can press and then it will get all dates and post them somewhere). At the moment I just need somehow to get the date values.

At first the values are loaded from XML, but you can change the values manually.

I tried looking into source code, but was not able to get the field IDs etc.

**So how I can access those fields with JS?**

Comment: That is an Extjs component, look at the documentation: http://bryntum.com/docs/

Comment: When saying 'current', which line do you mean? there are 9 start and end dates...

Comment: @Kuf : well if I even could get one of these, I could get others also, hehe. Current meaning, you can change the values, by pressing on the date there. So whenever user presses button, means current. I'm not sure I am getting downvoted, its a reasonable question. Maybe I need to explain more, I'm not sure, ask if you have questions.

Comment: unfortunately, there's no unique id on the divs so you can't access them. but they seem to have unique `class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-startdatecolumn-1011"` and `class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-enddatecolumn-1014"` values, create a javascript like this `document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-enddatecolumn-1014")` to access them and then you can get their start and end dates

Comment: @ClydeFrog clyde I haven't tested this yet, but this was something I was looking for, thanks, you should post it as answer, and if it works, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're still looking for JS solution:

I couln't use Jquery, does the server support it?

By using JS, since the cells do not have an ID, you can access your fields by class name:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-cell-inner ");
```

And than iterating trough the returned array.

Complete code:

```
var data = document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-cell-inner ");
var mark = 0;
var out = "";
var patt=/\d\/\d/;
for (i in data) {
    var txt = new String(data[i].innerHTML);
    if (patt.test(txt)) {
        if (mark == 0) {
            out += "start: "+txt+" ";
            mark = 1;
        } else {
            mark = 0;
            out += "end: "+txt+" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be totally wrong to do this with jquery - It's an Extjs component with really good documentation.

`Gnt.panel.Gantt` has a `getStart` method:

> Method to get a the current start date of the scheduler view

and a `getEnd` method:

> Method to get a the current end date of the scheduler view

http://bryntum.com/docs/#!/api/Gnt.panel.Gantt

**Edit:**

Try `getTaskStore`, then `getById` on the store witch will return a `Task` that has a StartDate and EndDate fields.

Comment: I will try it out and let you know. Yeah the jQuery was just a guess, I certainly must not use it. :P

Comment: Okay tested it out, it does not get the "task" startDate, but it gets the startDate of the graphic, so when you look the link in my first post, startDate() returns Mon 04 Jan 2010, which is where the graphic "starts". So not really what I need.

Comment: @jaanus: I've edited my answer. (reading the documentation might help you even better)

Comment: Yep I found that also, thanks, I'll try to get it to work atm.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there's no unique id on the divs so you can't access them. but they seem to have unique `class=""` values:

`class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-startdatecolumn-1011"`

`class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-enddatecolumn-1014"`

create a javascript like this

`document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-enddatecolumn-1014")`

to access them and then you can get their start and end dates